# Solved: How to dynamically send E-Mails from multiple SMTP Servers (Java SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, smtp, mime-message

### Current state

I have a Java SpringBoot api, which at the moment is able to dynamically send an E-Mail with javax.mail.MimeMessage. The credentials are passed as parameters (E-Mail-Address, Password, SMTP-Server, SMTP-Port). When I start the application and send the first E-Mail everything works fine.

### Problem

However when I try to send another E-Mail from a different SMTP-Server, it seems that the E-Mail gets sended from the first SMTP-Server and credentials. In, for example Googlemail, every E-Mail shows the sender as well as the (SMTP-)Server which it's sended from. While the sended E-Mail-Address displays the new E-Mail-Address, the "Send from" (SMTP-Server) still shows the old SMTP-Server.

### Goal

So what I want, is to be able to send multiple E-Mails from individual SMTP-Servers and E-Mail-Addresses, passed by parameters.

### Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/send-email")
public class EmailController {

    public EmailController(){}

    @PostMapping
    public SentEmail sendEmail(@RequestBody SendEmailInformation sendEmailInformation) {
        EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
        return emailService.sendEmail(sendEmailInformation);
    }

}
```

### E-Mail-Service

```
{
    private Transport transport;

    public EmailService() {}

    public void sendEmail(SendEmailInformation sendEmailInformation) {
        try{
            String fromEmail = sendEmailInformation.getEmailAddress();
            String password = sendEmailInformation.getPassword();
            String toEmail = sendEmailInformation.getEmail();

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", sendEmailInformation.getSmtpServer());
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", sendEmailInformation.getSmtpPort());
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            };

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
            msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(sendEmailInformation.getEmail(), false));
            msg.setSubject(sendEmailInformation.getSubject(), "UTF-8");
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            messageBodyPart.setText(sendEmailInformation.getMessage());

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            msg.setContent(multipart);

            transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(msg,msg.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            transport.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                transport.close();
            }catch (Exception ignored) {

            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new CouldNotSendEmailException();
        }
    }
}
```

### I already tried

At first, I had the Email-Service as a @Bean and figured, that I should try to create a new Object for every call as I do now. So using a @Bean does not work. Also in my understanding, closing the Transport Object with transport.close(); at the end should help my problem, however it didnt't.

### Question

Does anyone have an idea, what could solve my Problem?

Thanks in advance.

*Edit*

### Solution

Looking for my code many days in a row and never saw the mistake, then posting this question and just minutes later having the idea that `Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);` might be the problem... yes it is! This always uses the same Session object, instead of creating a new one.

For those who are facing the same problem:
Just use `Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);` instead. Hope I could help someone with that.